# Fastest Way to Parse this String in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am currently looking for the fastest way to parse a string in Ruby. The string has the format:

> "#{String1}>#{String2}(#{Integer})", for example "Hello>World(25)"

and I am looking to retrieve the values of String1, String2, and Integer out of it. My current way of doing it is just

```
s1 = "Hello"
s2 = "World"
i = 25
str = "#{s1}>#{s2}(#{i})"
str = str.split('>')
newStr = str[1].split('(')
str[1] = newStr[0]
str[2] = newStr[1].chomp(')').to_i
print(str)   # => ["Hello", "World", 25]`
```

I am looking for any way faster than this to speed up my program. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed over readability, you're probably really close to the fastest you're going to get. I was able to shave a little bit of time off of your implementation by passing the optional `limit` parameter to `split` and omitting the `chomp(')')` which isn't needed:

```
  # Way #1
  str = str.split('>', 2)
  newStr = str[1].split('(', 2)
  str[1] = newStr[0]
  str[2] = newStr[1].to_i
```

or, at right about the same speed (it's faster in some runs, slower in others):

```
  # Way #2
  str = str.split(/[>(]/, 3)
  str[2] = str[2].to_i
```

Comment: Way #1 worked perfectly, chopped off ~5ms off of my average runtime. Way #2 added ~15ms to it however. Either way, way #1 answered my question perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

String [partition method](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/partition) is even faster than `split` method.

```
str = "Hello>World(25)"

a, _, b = str.partition('>')
b, _, c = b.partition('(')
c = c.to_i

puts a, b, c
```

Comment: This is indeed the fastest way

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex capture groups to obtain these values:

```
str = "Hello>World(25)"
s1, s2, i = str.match(/(\w+)>(\w+)\((\d+)\)/i).captures
```

Comment: I just tested this method, and while it is much easier to read, it slows down the execution of my program by ~12%

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex inside your `#split` method to achieve the same result:

```
string = "Hello>World(25)"
result = string.split(/[>,()]/)
result[-1] = result[-1].to_i

result
# => ["Hello", "World", 25]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tested this method, and while it is much easier to read, it slows down the execution of my program by ~9%